# Div color does not render properly

Tags: css

I have used few divs to organize my page, but the problem is in the div that acts like a footer. It has the same color property as the header #1D0870 ( dark blue ), but is not displaying it property.

The color in the footer is little bit lighter that it really should be. I have tried with overflow:auto and hidden and clear:both CSS properties but still no luck.

```
#footer {
position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#1D0870;       
    width: 98.5%;}
```

**Full code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/sR87v/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an optical illusion.

They're both the exact same color.

---

To prove it, here's the image, just rotated 180 degrees, where the "Lorum" part now looks lighter:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. They're the same color.

Comment: If you use a color picker tool they both come out to hex: 1d0870

Comment: @SteveWellens - which is exactly what I did in Photoshop.